# Disable/hide graphic/interface elements of a web site

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, website, graphics

Is there a way, for instance a Firefox/Chrome plugin, to hide, or even better 'disable' any graphic/design of a website in order to have a simplified, only 'plain text' version of it?

This could be useful to spare bandwidth, since it would be not necessary any more do down-load all the images and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you *might* want to use a text-mode browser.

The obvious one is [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser))

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For Chrome you can try and use [Text Mode](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-mode/adelhekhakakocomdfejiipdnaadiiib)

and for Firefox you can use [Textise](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12145)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to conserve bandwidth:

- [Use Google Mobilizer via a bookmarklet or configure it to run a URL
  with a keyword from the browser's address bar](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2012/04/google-mobilizer-bookmarklet-view-just.html) to see just the
  textual content.
- [Use mobile version of popular websites](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2012/04/low-bandwidth-try-mobile-version-of.html) for minimalistic & lighter pages
- [Readability browser add-ons](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2010/07/view-clutter-free-web-pages-with.html) can help you get clutter-free web pages
- [Block images/image ads originating from a specific domain easily in Firefox](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2011/09/how-to-block-imagesimage-ads.html) as well as [IFrame ads](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2007/02/how-to-block-iframe-based-ads.html) to cut down on bandwidth consumed.